# Load and external Url and Maintain the WebView hidden

Tags: android, webview

have an Android Activity with a Vertical LinearLayout. The first screen component is a simple TextView and right below a WebView with visiblity gone.

The web page has javascript code to communicate with the server, there is no visual components. So I need to maintain it with visibility gone, that is hidden, no space occupied in the activity screen.

Then problem is that when I execute webView.loadUrl. it opens the device browser. In the emulator it switches to a another activity with the webview occupping all screen.

How can I make it work ? How can I load and maintain webView completely hidden

Thanks in advance

My layout is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#ffe3d0">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Demo: WebView"
            android:layout_gravity="center" style="@style/MainLabel" android:autoText="false" android:id="@id/mainLabel"
            android:textColor="#3c3f41"/>
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@id/webView" android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/secondTextView"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:textColor="#1635ff" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity code is like that:

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: By AsyncTask function try to call your url and to hide all the screen by progress bar...

Comment: Sorry I am new to Android development. How can I do that ? Do you have any piece of code. I have added in the original question text a copy of my files